# How to calculate $\iiint\limits_V z^2 dxdydz$, where $V$ is determined by a ball and another constraint

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How to calculate $\iiint\limits_V z^2 dxdydz$, where $V$ is determined by $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le r^2$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 2rz$?

The solution seems odd to me because they only consider $0\le z \le r$.

---

Solution:

Let $S: x^2 + y^2 \le 2rz -z^2 (0 \le z \le r/2); Q: x^2+y^2 \le r^2 - z^2 (r/2 \le z \le r)$. Then,

$$\begin{split}
\iiint\limits_V z^2 dxdydz &= \int_0^{r/2}dz \iint\limits_S z^2 dxdy + \int_{r/2}^r dz \iint\limits_Q z^2 dxdy 
\\&= \pi\int_0^{r/2} z^2(2rz-z^2)dz + \pi \int_{r/2}^rz^2(r^2 - z^2)dz
\end{split}$$

Comment: We even do not have access to the odd solution... Please provide content! (Own tries should come, where do the two spheres intersect... etc)

Comment: Assume $r>0$.  The first inequality implies $|z|\leq r$ and the second implies $z\geq 0$

Comment: Have you tried to envision your solid $V$?

Comment: $x^2+y^2+z^2 \geq 0$ and so the second constraint means $z \geq 0$. The first constraint means $z \leq r$.

Comment: Write second one as $x^2 + y^2 + (z-r)^2 \le r^2$ which is another sphere with center on $z$ axis. Can you see its center is on the surface of the first sphere? Similarly see that the center of the first is on the surface of the second.

Comment: @MathLover I can see the two spheres now. I added a solution, but I do not know why they solve it that way.

Comment: Find their intersection by equating $x^2+y^2+z^2$. You will get $z = \frac{r}{2}$. Now for $0 \leq z \leq \frac{r}{2}$, area of cross sections $\pi(x^2+y^2)$ is from the second sphere. Then for $\frac{r}{2} \leq z \leq r$, area of cross sections is from the first sphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first ball, $x^2+y^2+z^2\le r^2$, is centered at the origin $(0,0,0)$ with radius $r$.

The second ball, $x^2+y^2+z^2\le 2rz$, or upon completing the square with respect to $z$, $x^2+y^2+(z-r)^2\le r^2$, is centered at $(0,0,r)$ and also has radius $r$.

The spheres that bound the balls intersect at

$$x^2+y^2+(z-r)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2\implies r^2-2rz=r(r-2z)=0\implies z=\frac r2$$

which corresponds to a circle in the plane $z=\frac r2$ with equation

$$x^2+y^2+\left(\frac r2\right)^2=r^2\implies x^2+y^2=\frac{3r^2}4$$

i.e. a circle centered at $\left(0,0,\frac r2\right)$ with radius $\frac{\sqrt3\,r}2$ and parallel to the $(x,y)$ plane.

So, the region $V$ is the set of points

$$V=\left\{(x,y,z) \mathrel{\bigg|} -\frac{\sqrt3}2\le x\le \frac{\sqrt3}2\,\land\,-\sqrt{\frac{3r^2}4-x^2}\le y\le\sqrt{\frac{3r^2}4-x^2}\,\land\,r-\sqrt{r^2-x^2-y^2}\le z\le\sqrt{r^2-x^2-y^2}\right\}$$

That is, $z$ is bounded below by the bottom half of the *upper* sphere, and bounded above by the top half of the *lower* sphere.

Integrating in rectangular coordinates seems like too much of a hassle to me, so I suggest converting to cylindrical:

$$\begin{cases}x=u\cos v\\y=u\sin v\\z=w\end{cases}$$

Then the integration region is

$$V'=\left\{(u,v,w) \mathrel{\bigg|} 0\le u\le\frac{\sqrt3\,r}2 \,\land\, 0\le v\le2\pi \,\land\, r-\sqrt{r^2-u^2}\le w\le\sqrt{r^2-u^2}\right\}$$

and the integral is

$$\begin{align}
\iiint_Vz^2\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz&=\iiint_{V'}w^2u\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv\,\mathrm dw\\[1ex]
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\sqrt3\,r}2}\int_{r-\sqrt{r^2-u^2}}^{\sqrt{r^2-u^2}}w^2u\,\mathrm dw\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv
\end{align}$$